# Отправить на печать ОДИН div из всей страницы (html/css)

Tags: css, html, печать

Не могу решить такую задачу. Нужно отправлять на печать не всю html/css страницу, а только один внутренний div с таблицей (строк много - больше чем на одну страницу).

Пробовала использовать media print - лишние блоки, перечисленные в правиле, пропадают при отправке на печать, но пустое пространство на странице остается. Кроме того таблица обрезается в конце первой страницы и дальше не печатается. Такой результат не подходит.

Пробовала сделать по материалам, ссылка на которые дана здесь: Печать отдельного блока страницы

Но получаю при печати сокрытие всех блоков, включая тот, который нужно напечатать.

Пишу в css:
.noprint { display: none; }
.print { display: block; }

Создаю в html сразу после открывающего body div class="noprint" И закрываю этот блок перед закрывающим body

А таблицу, которую НУЖНО напечатать, оборачиваю в div class="print" И получаю пустую страницу при печати

Подскажите, как добиться нужного результата. Спасибо!

```css
/* Сброс стилей */
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;} 
/* Конец сброса стилей*/
html { 
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%; } /* Браузерное умолчание, т.е. 16px  */ 
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.6875;
  font-family: Georgia;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#main {      
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
#main > article { 
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #87a7b1;
  border-radius: 7pt;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  flex: 3 1 60%;
  order: 2;
  text-align:justify;
}
/*Стили для адаптивной таблицы*/
.responstable {
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #024457;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #167F92;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.responstable tr {
  border: 1px solid #BEC7C7;
}
.responstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}
.responstable th {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #D9E4E6;
  background-color: #cecece;
  color: #000000;
  /*padding: .5em;*/
  font-size: .8em;
}
.responstable th:first-child {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
.responstable th:nth-child(2) {
  display: table-cell;
}
.responstable th:nth-child(2) span {
  display: none;
}
.responstable th:nth-child(2):after {
  content: attr(data-th);
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .responstable th:nth-child(2) span {
    display: block;
  }
  .responstable th:nth-child(2):after {
    display: none;
  }
}
.responstable td {
  display: inline;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 7em;
}
.responstable td:first-child {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #D9E4E6;
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .responstable td {
    border: 2px solid #D9E4E6;
  }
}
.responstable th, .responstable td {
  text-align:center;
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .responstable th, .responstable td {
    display: table-cell;
    /*padding: 1em;*/
  }
}
/*Конец стилей таблицы*/

@media print {
  * {
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }
  .print, .print * {
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
  .print {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <article title="Трехкомнатные квартиры в аренду от 22-31.01.17" class="content">
    <h3 style="display:inline">&nbsp;</h3>
    <div class="print">
      <div class="cover-table" title='1 + TV, 
                                      2 + Холодильник, 
                                      3 + Стир.маш, 
                                      4 + телефон, 
                                      5+ Интернет'><table class="responstable">
        <tr>
          <th><span>Кол-во<br /> комнат</span></th>
          <th data-th=", Характеристики">Адрес, р-н</th>
          <th>Метро</th>
          <th>S <br /><br />о<br />б<br />щ</th>
          <th>S <br /><br />к<br />о<br />м<br />н</th>
          <th>S<br /><br />к<br />у<br />х</th>
          <th>Эт</th>
          <th>С/у</th>
          <th>Тип дома</th>
          <th><strong>Цена</strong></th>
          <th>Срок</th>
          <th>Примечания</th>
          <th>T<br />V</th>
          <th>Х<br />о<br />л</th>
          <th>С<br />т<br />М</th>
          <th>Т<br />е<br />л</th>
          <th>И<br />н<br />т</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1к.кв.</td>
          <td>ул.Софьи Ковалевской, д.5, корп.5, Калининский р-н</td>
          <td>Академич,    10 мин.пешком</td>
          <td>45</td>
          <td>(18+12)</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>4/7</td>
          <td>разд    с/у</td>
          <td>пан</td>
          <td>11мес</td>
          <td>Меб+</td>
          <td><strong>+</strong></td>
          <td><strong>+</strong></td>
          <td><strong>-</strong></td>
          <td><strong>-</strong></td>
          <td><strong>-</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1к.кв.</td>
          <td>Гражданский пр-кт, д.19, корп.3, Калининский р-н</td>
          <td>Академическая, 7 м.п.</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>5/9</td>
          <td>совм с/у</td>
          <td>Кирп</td>
          <td><strong>16.000</strong></td>
          <td>12мес</td>
          <td>Только Кух/Меб, +КУ, +Свет, Залог 50 %, Чисто, Хор/Сост, Без/Меб, Кух/Меб,    Окна-Двор, Окна-Зелень, Ванна Сидячая, Газ/Плита, Не Рассм    Гастарб/Рабоч/Строит, Гражд/РФ, Для 1-3 Чел &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table></div></div>
  </article></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то такое:

```css
@media print {
  * {
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }

  .print, .print * {
    visibility: visible !important;
  }

  .print {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: не помогло, увы.

Comment: @Наталья, тогда для ответа недостаточно сведений. [mcve].

Comment: как ни правила я код для вставки сюда, все равно он текстом отобразился. не знаю, что неправильно сделала. Но, вот ОНО, сильно уменьшенное по количеству строк. Хотя нагляднее было бы на специализированных сервисах.

Comment: @Наталья, не воспроизводится на приведённом примере. Всё работает как ожидалось.

Comment: @Наталья, https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1dZa.png

Comment: Да, теперь на печать выводятся только данные из таблицы. Но они обрезаются в конце первой страницы, как и раньше. Там только две строки. Я просто не стала всю "простыню" сюда копировать. Если данных больше, чем на 1 страницу, они не отображаются при печати (в предпросмотре тоже)

Comment: @Наталья, это, вероятно, к этому вопросу уже не относится. Надо просто подогнать стили. Ну или размер бумаги. Ну или масштаб (`transform: scale(...)`) для печати.

Answer (score 0):

Так дело не пойдет. Если Вы скрываете `<div>`, то весь контент **внутри** него так-же будет невидим, независимо от того что там. Даже если там `display: block;` — не важно.

Пустое пространство которое остается в первом случае, вероятнее всего возникает из-за отступов (`pading`, `margin`) или ограничений ширины (`width`).